# Does smtp in php really send messages to specified email address in localhost machine?

Tags: php

I have written a code in php using mail function and configured php sendmail ini fills properly. And our mail function return true but I didn't get mail to our specified email address. I don't know is this message actually sent or not. I have googled and also read many blogs but didn't get the real answer. Please clear my doubt

Comment: Have you checked junk?

Comment: I have read this blog. But I didn't get my answer

Comment: Junk... ??? How can I check and what is it?

Comment: Junk mail = Spam mail.

Comment: No I didn't get any spam mail

Comment: First I want to clear I am using xampp on my local machine. And I didn't buy any mail service or anything. Is it possible in this case to send mail to any email address